# direct ac mains to MCU pin for zero crossing detection

Tags: 8051, zero-crossing

to detect Zero Crossing of ac mains, can i connect an EFM8 pin configured as input directly to 220V ac via a resistor?

Comment: This is one of those questions: If you have to ask, the answer is **NO**.

Comment: Agreed. Use opto-isolated zero-cross detection.

Comment: @turbo-j: it's not always the case!!!...

Comment: @Transistor: there is no room for an OC circuitry or the like...

Comment: Then you probably haven't even got room for proper isolation distance between the mains and the low voltage section. You will have to treat the whole circuit as live.

Comment: @Transistor: in the pcb design mains traces are suffisiantly isolated from low signal traces...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the EFM8 input pins have clamping diodes, yes, using two 1Mohm resistors. One resistor connects the input to AC Line, and the other connects ground to AC Neutral. Note that there is **no isolation** and the entire MCU circuit should be considered to be at mains voltage.

See [AVR182](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-2508-Zero-Cross-Detector_ApplicationNote_AVR182.pdf) for further details and considerations.

Comment: efm8 datasheets and ref manuals are not clear concerning the presence or not of clamping diodes!...

Comment: @moyoumos: Looking at the Sleepy Bee EFM8SB1 datasheet, the Absolute Maximum Rating for V_IN suggests that they are in place.

Comment: i have only EFM8BB3, LB12 and UB3 devices... will see if this is a common or a special feature...